# How is the recursive function returning 33?

Tags: c, recursion

I have been stuck on this one for hours now

This is the code that I am not able to get a hold of :

```
before recursive call sum value8  
before recursive call sum value12 
before recursive call sum value12  
before recursive call sum value14 
after recursive call sum value14  
after recursive call sum value33 
after recursive call sum value33  
after recursive call sum value33  
sum value in main33
```

```
#include<stdio.h>

int foo(int n,int sum)
{
    int k=0,j=0;

    if(n==0) return sum;

    k=n%10;
    j=n/10;
    sum+=k;
    printf("before recursive call sum value%d\n",sum);

    sum=foo(j,sum);

    printf("after recursive call sum value%d\n",sum);
}

int main()
{
    int a=2048,sum=0;
    sum=foo(a,sum);

    printf("sum value in main%d\n",sum);
}
```

The output is also present in the code.

I have traced the function calls using a stack and I expected a value of 14 to be returned to the calling function(main()) but I am getting an output of 33 which I find difficult to understand.

**Even If I assume I traced the recursion wrong somewhere, aren't all digits returned at any point of time even so how can their sum be 33 which is odd?**

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. You have a *huge* control path in `foo` that gives *no* return value (i.e. there is no `return something;`). Your code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried executing it many times just to be sure and it seems to consistently give 33 as the output . If it was some undefined value, shouldn't the value change at each run? The constant value '19' seems to be added everytime which seems to cause the confusion!

Comment: Undefined behavior has no explanation, and needs none.

Comment: Ok I understood the fallacy in my argument Thanks David

Comment: Why should the value change at each run? Sometimes undefined values do that and sometimes they don't.

Comment: It is 33 because the string "after recursive call sum valueXX\n" has 33 characters. Which will be the return value of the second `printf`, which will then be *accidentally* reused as the return value of `foo`. Undefined behavior is undefined, but in this case it is pretty easy to explain. Of course, this can change next time you compile.

Comment: @Art I am not quite sure what you mean exactly however I will look into it . Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never return a value in `foo()` for the non base case.  Try returning the sum instead:

```
int foo(int n, int sum)
{
    int k=0, j=0;

    if (n == 0) return sum;

    k = n % 10;
    j = n / 10;
    sum += k;
    printf("before recursive call sum value%d\n", sum);

    sum = foo(j, sum);
    printf("after recursive call sum value%d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim . I will be selecting your answer. It makes perfect sense to me now what the problem with my code was.

Comment: @Denson I'm not a C/C++ person, but this problem jumped out at me.  Actually, in many other programming languages, such as Java, your code would not even have compiled and it would have been obvious what was wrong.

Comment: Exactly my point Tim, even I am a Java person. So I didn't see through it!

Comment: @Denson Add `-Wall` to your compiler switches (if you are using gcc or clang that is), it would have diagnosed the problem.

Comment: Thanks M.M, I am using gcc I will keep this in mind.